# How firestore data architecture for restaurants

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

we have an order tracking application for restaurants, and we use firestore.

We have some questions about database architecture. How should we keep the data?

We currently store orders as follows

**server / {restaurant} / orders / {OrderID}**

Each order document contains the tableName parameter, and we query it with the tableName field when taking orders for a table and paying for the table.

Should this be the right architecture?

**server / {restaurant} / tables / {TableID} / orders / {OrderID}**

**server / {restaurant} / tables / {TableID} / payments / {paymentıd}**

This is the standart restaurant system you can image it.

***Restaurant have a lot of table, in this tables have orders and payments, this is the how it works...***

Comment: What are the queries you want to perform?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for reply, we need the all tables, and in this tables orders and payments.. and we store the product statistics vs...

we now use get all orders to redux and filter by table name and show the tables payments and orders.. this system is standart restaurant order system you can imagene

Answer (score 1):

This is a highly opinionated and application specific question.

With Firestore / NoSQL I suggest first prototyping your application from the user's perspective. What are the different screens and associated data on each screen. This will help you identify the different queries and read/write operations that are frequently performed and how to best structure your firestore.

For example: It may be that you keep Table Orders in separate unique documents, but also that one of the screens includes a 'summary of orders' where a user can view the previous 100 orders. This requirement may dictate that you also want to include a summary document that contains those previous orders so that when the user views your summary screen you are not being charged 100 read operations, and instead only 1.

- Start by prototyping your views
- Identify the data model for each view
- Identify the queries you will need to perform
- Start putting together a database infrastructure that is performant for the above requirements